# Java/OSGi modifying existing application into an OSGi service

Tags: java, osgi

I am quite new to OSGi and everything that is close to that.

Jump into the problem: I have a server-class that keeps a list of listeners, the listeners can register theirselves via a method (`register(this)`) that puts the listener into that above mentioned list (all listeners implement the server-class listener interface of course):

```
public void register(ServerListener listener) {
    if(theListeners == null)
        theListeners = new ArrayList<ServerListener>();

    theListeners.add(listener);
}
```

That's the `ServerListener` interface:

```
public interface ServerListener {
    public void update(JsonObject data);
}
```

Now the server-class provides the listeners with new data from time to time via an `update(JsonObject object)` method.

```
public void updateListeners() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for(ServerListener l : theListeners) {
                l.update(jsonObject);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Now, I want to modify the server-class into a service bundle in an OSGi framework (Knopflerfish). I am not familiar with that at all. I want to try just for fun, but the way I am doing it right now would not work, the listeners actually don't know that they should implement the `ServerListener` interface. So the server can't register them via the interface.

The thing is, I want to server to push data, not the clients to pull (that would be easier, in my understanding). Can someone (who understood my poor explanation) point me in the right direction?

Comment: "the listeners actually don't know that they should implement the ServerListener interface". How do you call them then?

Comment: in the current implementation the listeners implement the interface, works. if now another developer with his client implementation wants to get data from the server, he should implement the serverlistener interface somehow (right?), but where should that interface be specified/put? in the server bundle wouldn't be the right place for that. do i need something like a core bundle, in which this kind of general interfaces and classes are specified? but anyways, the new client wouldn't have access also to a interface specified in another bundle, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An 'OSGi-centric' approach is to use a pattern known as the whiteboard pattern, rather than the listener pattern as you might with plain Java. Instead of registering with the server-class, your listeners register as services with the OSGi service registry. This means the framework takes care of handling registration, unregistration, and listeners which go away.

There's a free whitepaper on the whiteboard pattern here: http://www.osgi.org/wiki/uploads/Links/whiteboard.pdf, and we've also got a discussion of it in chapter 5 of *Enterprise OSGi in Action* (http://www.manning.com/cummins ).

It can take a while to get your head wrapped around the listener pattern, because it's your listeners which provide services, and your 'server' which consumes the services, which feels backwards at first. Once you get used to it, though, it works really well. Your server consumes all the services which implement the ServiceListener interface, and pushes data out to them as required.

It's best not to use the OSGi APIs directly to register and consume the services - use either declarative services (SCR) or blueprint for dependency injection of the OSGi services. These allow you to register and consume the services with an XML metadata file or annotations.

(As other have suggested, using a package-level dependencies for the ServerListener interface should allow it to be imported by both the server and listener bundles, no matter which bundle exports the package.)

Answer (score 4):

You've got multiple problems here:

1. You need to expose a service (the server class) for other objects to register with
2. Interested objects need to find the service in order to register themselves
3. The other objects need to implement a particular interface for this to work

In general, trying to retrofit existing code into the OSGi can be painful unless you already have a modular architecture.

The listener interface can live in the server bundle or you could put it in a seperate API/contract bundle - both are valid designs.

From how you are describing the problem it sounds like you don't know the different types of dependency you can have in OSGi.

Coming from traditional Java development, most developers will start with the 'my dependencies are based on JARs' - this is not the best model.

OSGi offers package-level dependencies. In this way as long as some bundle offers the needed package, you're bundle doesn't care which bundle/JAR provided the dependency.

So if you used a package-level dependency for your listener interface, the implementation doesn't need to care if it comes from the server bundle or a contract/API bundle.

As a final note your design tightly couples the server to the listeners. What happens if a listener fails? Or hangs? Pub/sub is a better model for this type of communication.

* edit *

And Holly's answer reminded me again of the whiteboard pattern - definitely a good idea.